# How to access async data in a factory across multiple controllers without using promises

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to store some user data in a service that will be accessible and modified across different controllers, and the data will be initially pulled via a $http call. Since the data has to be loaded, I've used promises in my previous code, but this can be quite irritating to write. For instance, even a basic getter function has to be written as the following

```
UserData.getData().then(function(data) {
    //do something with the data
})
```

where UserData.getData() always returns a promise via `deferred.promise` (if the data has already been pulled, then resolve immediately). I'm wondering if there is anyway to split a) $http calls, and b) getter and setter methods into two different services so that if I call getter and setter methods from b), I don't need to wrap everything with `then`?

For instance, I'm trying to make UserFactory in charge of the $http call, and UserData in charge of getters and setters. However, I can't get the code to work since UserData.getData() will return undefined, and wondering if anyone can help? (I don't really want to have to use `then` everywhere).

```
angular.module('testApp', [])
//mocks a service that gets data from a server
.factory('UserFactory', function($timeout, $q) {
    return {
        getData: function() {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            $timeout(function() {
                deferred.resolve({title: 'hello world'});
            }, 1000);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }
})
.factory('UserData', function(UserFactory) {
    var data;

    return {
        //if already pulled, use existing data
        getData: function() {
            if (data) return data;
            UserFactory.getData().then(function(res) {
                data = res;
                return data;
            })
        }
    }
})
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QNLk2/1/

Comment: Why let you leak the promise out of your `UserFactory`? You can design a simpler interface which prevents the need to deal with a promise whenever you call it.

Comment: Hi @Sebastian, thanks for the reply! Do you have any suggestions on what sort of interface I could build? I'm not sure how to do it without promises.

Comment: I check your fiddle and it works for me. After a delay of 1s the correct data is returned. Isn't that what you would expect?

Comment: @Sebastian Well, it would return undefined if you click it immediately since it is an async operation. I can get it to work with promises, but I don't want to always have to be writing '.then(function(data){xxx})' as it is quite verbose

Answer (score 0):

The then method is executed asynchronously so the return method as no effect there. That is why until the data has arrived every call to getData will return undefined.

You can try the following approach, where you can specify a callback if you want to be notified when data is ready, or simply wait for the data to be populated in the return variable.

```
.factory('UserData', function(UserFactory) {
    var data = {};

    return {
        getData: function(callback) {
            UserFactory.getData().then(function(res) {
                angular.extend(data, res);
                if (callback) {
                    callback(data);
                }
            });
            return data;
        }
    }
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this! I can get it to work if I used a callback or a promise, but it seems quite verbose - I was hoping to be able to directly call getData(), and have it a) return the data immediately if it has been pulled, b) return the date later if it hasn't been pulled yet. Wondering if that is possible